# Having problem with Javascript function to retrieve image reference in Firestore web

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a post from Firestore, that will appear in a card, which will include, card-image and card-content. The code below was able to create a card with card-content, but the `image` is not showing, only an icon has been displayed, but not the image data. There are no errors in the console.`title` and `summary` have been received and shown in the Card.

I think what I did is not the proper way to retrieve an image from Firestore

```js
//Create Post
function createPost(image, title, summary) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-4 mb-4');

  let divCard = document.createElement('div');
  divCard.setAttribute('class', 'card');

  let divCardImg = document.createElement('div');
  divCardImg.setAttribute('class', 'view');

  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('class', 'card-img-top');

  let divContent = document.createElement('div');
  divContent.setAttribute('class', 'card-body');

  let h4 = document.createElement('h4');
  h4.setAttribute('class', 'card-title');

  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.setAttribute('class', 'card-text');

  img.src = image;
  h4.textContent = title;
  p.textContent = summary;

  divContent.appendChild(h4);
  divContent.appendChild(p);
  divCard.appendChild(divContent);
  divCardImg.appendChild(img);
  divCard.appendChild(divCardImg);
  div.appendChild(divCard);

  fashionCollection.appendChild(div);
}

// Get Posts
function getPosts() {
  db.collection("post")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(docs => {
        createPost(
          docs.data().image,
          docs.data().title,
          docs.data().summary
        );
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

getPosts();
```

The `createPost` function creates a card post with certain attributes, and the `getPost` function retrieves the data.

Please let some help me fix this.

Comment: can you expand on "the image is not showing." is there any data coming back? If so what does the image variable hold? any errors in the console?

Comment: an img icon is display, but no image data is retrieved and there are no error in the console, and the Title and Summary is showing in the Card. I think what i did is not a proper way to retrieve image from firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how you store your image in Firestore.
If it is a url, then the problem might be in Storage permissions.
If it is base64 encoded and stored in [Bytes type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), then you will need to point that out in src attribute like this:

```
img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + image;
```

Keep in mind that storing images in Bytes type field is not good as they are limited to 1 MB, preferred way is to host images in Cloud Storage.